# VBA Visio - autoorder items by their value (alphabetically)

Tags: vba, visio

I would like to have my shapes in the following manner (as the red list on the right):
[image]

Unfortunately, my schematic comes initially in a quite chaotic order, as you can see on the left.

The alphabetical order is made only horizontally, but not vertically.

I tried to fight with the code, but it was rather swapping some "branches" around.

```
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(925), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1143), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(814), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1141), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1142), visSelect
      Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Move 0.224972, 2.302099

      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1144), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1017), visSelect
      ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1072), visSelect
      Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Move 0.151857, 2.238548
```

Another approach was:

```
    If Vshp.Name Like "*UG*" Then
        If Vshp.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU Like """"*NRTH-X*"""" Then
```

Sort Key1:=Range("SLD"), Order1:=xlAscending
End If
End If

I am having the error, that: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Is there a chance for ordering the shapes in ascending (alphabetical) manner, by their value, analogically to this thread:
[VBA visio - cannot change font size in the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056627/vba-visio-cannot-change-font-size-in-the-element)

**UPDATE:**

Tried to work with the answer below, but I keep receiving the following error:
**Object variable or with variable not set**

At the following line:

```
Sub texts()
Dim ViShp As Shape
Set ViShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
**If ViShp.Shapes(4).Characters.Text Like "*NRTH*" Then**
End If
End Sub
```

By this approach:

```
Sub textsel()
Dim ViShp As Shape
Dim Vs As Shape
Set ViShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
Set Vs = ViShp.Shapes(4)
If Vs.Characters.Text Like "*NRTH*" Then
End If
End Sub
```

Set Vs = ViShp.Shapes(4) - this is the line where the error appears.

Sometimes I also get this error:
**Requested operation is presently disabled**

[Run-time error '-2032465766 (86db089a)' "Requested operation is presently disabled."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440325/run-time-error-2032465766-86db089a-requested-operation-is-presently-disabl)

Is there any way to define the object for the sub-shape?

Comment: `If Vshp.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU Like """"*NRTH-X*"""" Then` this line have error, cell **Char.Size** must contain string like `12 pt`, i.e. font size in points (pt)!

Comment: So what option could fit the text value then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How works with text values

If you want to get the text of a shape programmatically you must use the [Text property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.text)
Use syntax like

`If Vshp.Text Like """"*NRTH-X*"""" Then`

Another way use [INSTR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

`If instr(Vshp.Text,"NRTH-X")>0 Then`

---

*This solution show how works with text, but not about auto-ordering*!

Sorry, I forgot than text like "*NRTH-X*" [have sub-shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76065983).
Also in your case this sub-shape have not text, there used field.
Try use syntax
`If Vshp.Shapes(4).Characters.Text Like "**NRTH-X**" Then`

Please look test at my side
[image: Sub-Shape with field]

In other threads, I've written to you many times that you use an intricate way of trying figures on a page.
IMHO Best way using [CreateSelection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.createselection)

Comment: The first one is automatically converted to:
If Vshp.Text Like """" * NRTH - x * """" Then
because of the spaces I have an error: Variable not defined - showing at NRTH

In the case of other one: Object required

Comment: Thanks, but still getting an error: Object variable or with variable not set

Comment: In which line does this error occur?

How do you do the enumeration of the figures on the sheet? If you do all the comparisons in a row with `like` operator, there is a good chance of an error! Because not all shapes have nested shapes, or may not have 4 shapes inside

Comment: If ViShp.Shapes(4).Characters.Text Like "*NRTH*"  - this is the line with error

Comment: **ViShp**? Please be accurate! Make sure that this shape have sub-shapes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253338/discussion-between-geographos-and-surrogate).